# CakePHP v2.4.3 record update and validation rules

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm trying to update one record with

```
$this->Model->id = 1;
$this->Model->save($this->request->data);
```

and to use validation rule 'on'=>'update'.

Is that possible and how :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem was to remove validation rule for the field that i don't want to validate when i update record.

```
 $this->Model->validator()->remove('fieldName');
 $this->Model->id = 1;
 $this->Model->save($this->request->data);
```